# Need proper query to filter according to date which is a relationship property in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a User label and a Follows relationship. Follows relationship has a property `ts`.
I want to get all the users that followed a particular user before a specific date.
However the query is not returning any records.

Get all followers

```
MATCH (b) WHERE id(b) = 172  MATCH (a)-[f:Follows]->(b) RETURN f.ts
```

Output:

> "2021-12-10T00:00:00"

Get all followers where ts is less than or equal to the date, 11th December, 2021

```
MATCH (b) WHERE id(b) = 172  MATCH (a)-[f:Follows]->(b) WHERE f.ts <= "DateTime({year:2021, month:12, day:11})" RETURN f.ts
```

Output:

> (no changes, no records)

In actuality, I want to compare the whole timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
WITH "2021-12-10T00:00:00" AS ts
RETURN DateTime(ts).year <= 2022
```

returning `true`

so, for you it would be

```
MATCH (b) 
WHERE id(b) = 172  
MATCH (a)-[f:Follows]->(b) 
WHERE DateTime(f.ts).year <= 2022 
RETURN f.ts
```

If you need to compare the entire date, you can do

```
WITH "2021-12-10T00:00:00" AS ts
RETURN DateTime(ts) <= DateTime({year:2021, month:12, day: 31})
```

Comment: Actually I want to compare the whole timestamp and not just the year. Updated the question

Comment: @Susmit see updated answer

Comment: Wrapping f.ts in datetime was a key here !